# Adding a subwindow into the Mainwindow

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

i added a draggable red circle into my main window. The red circle can be moved to anywhere you want on the main window. But i want to set a border where the red circle is allowed be move. Probably it should be done with a sub window? Anyone that has an idea how to do this? I come this far:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QWidget, QGraphicsEllipseItem, QMainWindow, QGroupBox, QGraphicsScene, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPointF, QRect


class MovingObject(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        #de meegegeven waardes gebruiken om beginpositie en grootte ellips te bepalen
        super().__init__(0, 0, r, r)
        self.setPos(x, y)
        self.setBrush(Qt.red)

    ##mousePressEvent checkt of er wel of niet wordt geklikt
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pass

    ##mouseMoveEvent is om de item te kunnen draggen
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        orig_cursor_position = event.lastScenePos()
        updated_cursor_position = event.scenePos()

        orig_position = self.scenePos()

        updated_cursor_x = updated_cursor_position.x() - orig_cursor_position.x() + orig_position.x()
        updated_cursor_y = updated_cursor_position.y() - orig_cursor_position.y() + orig_position.y()
        self.setPos(QPointF(updated_cursor_x, updated_cursor_y))


class GraphicView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 60, 60)


        #waardes x, y, r waarvan x en y beginpositie van ellips is en r is straal van ellips
        self.scene.addItem(MovingObject(0, 0, 40))

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(800, 500, 400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")

        #set GraphicView in Window
        self.graphicView = GraphicView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphicView)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

GUI = Window()
GUI.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's no need to reimplement mouse events to allow movements of a QGraphicsItem using the mouse, as setting the [`ItemIsMovable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum) flag is enough.

Once the flag is set, what is needed is to filter geometry changes and react to them.

This is achieved by setting the `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag and reimplementing the [`itemChange()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange) function. Using the `ItemPositionChange` change, you can receive the "*future*" position before it's applied and eventually change (and return) the received value; the returned value is the actual final position that will be applied during the movement.

What remains is to give a reference to check it.
In the following example I'm setting the *scene* rect (not the *view* rect as you did) with bigger margins, and set those margins for the item; you obviously can set any `QRectF` for that.

I also implemented the [`drawBackground()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#drawForeground) function in order to show the scene rect that are used as limits.

```
class MovingObject(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        super().__init__(0, 0, r, r)
        self.setPos(x, y)
        self.setBrush(Qt.red)
        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(self.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        self.margins = None

    def setMargins(self, margins):
        self.margins = margins

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == self.ItemPositionChange and self.margins:
            newRect = self.boundingRect().translated(value)
            if newRect.x() < self.margins.x():
                # beyond left margin, reset
                value.setX(self.margins.x())
            elif newRect.right() > self.margins.right():
                # beyond right margin
                value.setX(self.margins.right() - newRect.width())
            if newRect.y() < self.margins.y():
                # beyond top margin
                value.setY(self.margins.y())
            elif newRect.bottom() > self.margins.bottom():
                # beyond bottom margin
                value.setY(self.margins.bottom() - newRect.height())
        return super().itemChange(change, value)


class GraphicView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 120, 120)

        self.movingObject = MovingObject(0, 0, 40)
        self.scene.addItem(self.movingObject)
        self.movingObject.setMargins(self.scene.sceneRect())

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        painter.drawRect(self.sceneRect())
```

Do note that the graphics view framework is as powerful as it is hard to *really* know and understand. Given the question you're asking ("Probably it should be done with a sub window?") it's clear that you still need to understand how it works, as using sub windows is a completely different thing.
I strongly suggest you to carefully its [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) and **everything** (functions and properties) related to the [QGraphicsItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html), which is the base class for *all* graphics items.

<sub>Existing properties should *never* be overwritten; [`scene()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#scene) is a basic property of QGraphicsView, so you either choose another name as an instance attribute (`self.myScene = QGraphicsScene()`), or you just use a local variable (`scene = QGraphicsScene()`) and always use `self.scene()` outside the `__init__`.</sub>